# Column wise operation in Keras

Tags: keras

Suppose that I have a vector v and a matrix M -- they are not input but intermediate tensors resulting from other operations. I want to do a column-wise operation -- i.e., apply a function f for each column of M. That is,

Operation(v, M) = [f(v, M[:,i])] for i = 1 .. N.

What I did was the following (pseudo-code):

```
for i range(K.int_shape(M))[1]:
    column = Lambda(lambda x:x[:,i])(M) 
    ... <a code performing f(v, column)> ...
```

What I found is that, during run-time (i.e., model.fit()) column is identical inside the for-loop, instead of retrieving each column. I suspect that Lambda(lambda x:x[:,i]) is not a right way of retrieving a column in Keras.

What would be a right way of doing column-wise operation in matrix in Keras?

Comment: Depending on your `f`, it's probably better not use any loop at all. But only knowing `f` to surely say it's possible. (Often it is)

Comment: For instance, if the operations are sum, multiplication, etc., it can be done in a single line if you reshape the tensors correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue. lambda function in Python does a lazy evaluation. That is, it sets the value of i inside the lambda function not at the declaration time but at the execution time. That is the reason why all Lambda layer attempted to retrieve a single column which was the last one.

When I change the lambda function definition to `column = Lambda(lambda j:lambda x:x[:,j](i))(M)` it now works.